# Autoconf: Breaking long lines in strings

Tags: autoconf

In my `configure.ac` file I have warnings and errors like this one:

```
AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?])
```

I'm old-fashioned and like to keep the line width less than 80 characters. However, when I split the line like this (I like some proper indentation as well)

```
AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you
 specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?])
```

the error message keeps the line break and indentation when printed on the screen by `./configure`.

What is the proper way to break a string in Autoconf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing something like this it might be helpful to define M4 macros:

```
m4_define([bst_e1], [Could not find the Boost Math header files[,] did you])
m4_define([bst_e2], [specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?])
AC_MSG_ERROR(bst_e1 bst_e2)
```

You could also do this when the `configure` script is run, since `AC_MSG_ERROR` will take a variable:

```
variable=$(cat | tr '\012' ' ' <<ΕΟF
Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you
specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?
ΕΟF
)
AC_MSG_ERROR($variable)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I'm not convinced it makes the code easier to read, which was my intention. Nevertheless, I'll accept your the answer as it fulfils the requirements I set out in the question, even though it seems a little too involved for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but I found another solution, you can use `m4_normalize` like this:

```
AC_MSG_ERROR(m4_normalize([Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you 
             specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?]))
```

Or even:

```
AC_MSG_ERROR(m4_normalize([
    Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you
    specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?
]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, after reading a bit more and trying a few things out, it seems I can get rid of the line breaks in the output by breaking the string with a `\`, but it looks like I won't be able to keep the indentation in the source:

```
AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you \
specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?])
```

produces:

```
configure: error: Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?
```

whereas

```
AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you \
              specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?])
```

gives:

```
configure: error: Could not find the Boost Math header files, did you        specify the --with-boost-include-path option correctly?
```